# How to know user's "expiry_date" changed?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm faced with a very specific task with Oracle.
I need to prove that values in column `expiry_date` of table `dba_users` were not changed in a certain period (*during last weekend*).

I am not very experienced with Oracle. For me, it seems like a feature called "audit" is disabled, but I'm not strongly sure.

So, I need whatever option to check whether these values have been changed. I have already tried to analyze the `user_sessions` table (having the intent to check for connections during the period in question), but with that, I couldn't get an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to directly detect changes to `dba_users.expiry_date`, it would be much easier to detect when a user changes their password, which would indirectly change the expiry date:

```
select password_date
from sys.user_history$
join dba_users
    on sys.user_history$.user# = dba_users.user_id
where username = '&USER'
order by password_date desc;
```

However, that table will only contain values if the user has a profile where the PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME is not set to unlimited. You can find that setting with these queries:

```
--Find the user's profile:
select profile from dba_users where username = '&USER';

--Find the PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME of the profile.
--If the value is 'DEFAULT', you'll have to run this query again for the profile 'DEFAULT'.
select limit
from dba_profiles
where resource_name = 'PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME'
    and profile = '&PROFILE';
```

(Oracle's audit functionality does *not* capture this information. You can run `audit alter user` and then query `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` to detect when a user was changed, but you can't tell the difference between a password reset and an account locking.)

Unfortunately, the above solution doesn't cover all possible reasons why the expiration date could change. If an administrator manually expires a user, or changes a profile or profile settings, the expiration date could change. To capture all possible reasons for a change, you would need to create triggers on the system tables used by `DBA_USERS` and store the expiration value whenever it changes. Or you could create a job that periodically checks the view and looks for changes.

But before you consider those options, you might want to explain exactly why you want this information. I'm guessing this question is for a security audit, but this feels like the wrong kind of information to look for. What is your true goal here?